# ¿Cómo dejar espacios vacíos en un arreglo?

Tags: java, array

Tengo un proyecto de la universidad en el que se me pide llenar un arreglo de 20 elementos, pero hay un segundo requerimiento, en el que se me pide que si hay espacios sobrantes en el arreglo, agregue `*` al final del arreglo.

El problema es que no sé cómo hacer para que cuando el usuario no inserte los 20 elementos se agregue el `*` al final. He probado presionando la tecla enter únicamente, pero esto me arroja error.

Hasta el momento he intentado lo siguiente:

```
Scanner br = new Scanner(System.in);
int n = 0;
String leer;
char con;

System.out.println("\tIngrese 20 caracteres como máximo");
for (in = 0; in < 20; in++) {   
    System.out.println ("Cáracter número " + (n = n+1) +" ");
    leer = br.readLine();
    con = leer.charAt(0);
    arreglo [in] = con;
    //  System.out.println ("Carácter agregado ");
}

System.out.println ("Arreglo cargado");
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes hacerlo llenando primero todo el arreglo de asteriscos y luego llenando tus arreglo.

```java
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        char[] input = new char[20];
        char more;
        Arrays.fill(input, '*');

        for (int i = 0; i < input.length; ++i) {
            System.out.print("Ingrese el carácter " + (i + 1) + ": ");
            input[i] = scanner.next().charAt(0);
            System.out.println("¿Desea agregar más caracteres? (s/n): ");
            more = scanner.next().charAt(0);
            if (more != 's' && more != 'S')
                break;
        }

        System.out.println(input);
    }

}
```

O incluso mejor, llenas tu arreglo, solamente que si ya no quiere ingresar más caracteres, asumes que el carácter ingresado es '*'

```java
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        char[] input = new char[20];
        char more = 's';

        for (int i = 0; i < input.length; ++i) {
            if (more != 's' && more != 'S') {
                input[i] = '*';
                continue;
            }
            System.out.print("Ingrese el carácter " + (i + 1) + ": ");
            input[i] = scanner.next().charAt(0);
            System.out.println("¿Desea agregar más caracteres? (s/n): ");
            more = scanner.next().charAt(0);
        }

        System.out.println(input);
    }

}
```

Personalmente yo le dejaría ingresar un *String* de 20 o menos caracteres, porque estarle preguntando por cada carácter si quiere ingresar otro es muy tedioso.

Si mejor se introduce el *String* entero puede ser mucho más agradable, aunque ya depende de lo que te pidan